# What is my Azure password for azure-cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to spin up a Kubernetes cluster using my Microsoft Azure account. I'm following this guide:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/README.md#lets-go

At some point, the guide instructs to execute this command:

```
./azure-login.js -u <your_username>
```

I am pretty new to Azure, and I don't know what this username is. I have an e-mail that I use to login to the Azure Portal, where I can start virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that apparently one needs to have an organization account in order to use the Azure CLI tool. I had set up my account as an individual, with an e-mail address, so the tool wasn't working.

The solution was to convert my account to an organizational one by playing with the Active Directory service here, as explained here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-work-id-from-personal/

Answer (score -1):

A simple peek at `azure-login.js` (located in the same folder as the link you posted) shows:

```
require('child_process').fork('node_modules/azure-cli/bin/azure', ['login'].concat(process.argv));
```

So... it's calling the azure cli: `azure login username`

And username would be your email address for your Azure subscription (the same email address you'd login with in the portal). You'd then be prompted for your password.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. I had already taken that simple peek, and found out the script was calling the Azure cli. I am having the same issue with that as well. Namely, the username is *not* the e-mail that I use to login to the Azure Portal, and the command returns `AccountType: undefined`.

Comment: Well, not sure what to tell you, but I just tried it and it ran as I explained. But I can *guarantee* you that Azure logins are via email address (aside from domain-based federated accounts, but even those have email address logins associated with them).

Comment: Could it be because of the "type" of account that you have? At several places in the docs, they talk about a "school" or "work" account, but there is not much more information about this..